# Nginx config: Two Symfony apps for the same domain

Tags: php, symfony, nginx

I'm trying to achieve the following:

I have two versions of the same website. V2 is incomplete, but must have the priority against V1.
Eg. I have /admin/aaa and /admin/bbb, but only /admin/aaa is implemented in V2. And I should always try to load V2 first, then V1 if V2 throws a 404 error.

V1: Symfony 2.8, located in /var/www/site.dev (so should point to web/app.php)
V2: Symfony 3.3, located in /var/www/site-v2.dev (should point to public/index.php)

What I'm trying to achieve is the following, using nginx: `try_files $uri @v2 @v1;`

Does anyone know how I can handle this?

Thanks for your help!

Jonathan

Comment: you need a separate `server` block for each `server_name` and `root`. please post the server blocks you've already tried to configure.

Comment: Except the `server_name` is the same. Would it work?

Comment: I think, unless you can map every single (or group) uri which is unique to v1, you have to do this somewhere in php ;o/ but there is no such "fallback" I believe in nginx-land

Comment: @Jakumi It's a possibility. Do you have an example of how I could do it?

Comment: well, the `location` components might help you: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location inside the location you could set a different root directory for example